# jQuery select parent of element and use prependTo() for it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, parent

I am trying to restructure elements. The problem I face is that the elements do not have unique classes or IDs. So if, for example, a `.prependTo` is being called, it moves obviously all matching elements. HTML looks like this (important: real scenario contains hundreds of `<li>` elements):

```
<div id="top-element">          
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text-parent">
                <div class="text1">example</div>
                <div class="text2">example</div>
                <div class="text3">example</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text-parent">
                <div class="text1">example</div>
                <div class="text2">example</div>
                <div class="text3">example</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text-parent">
                <div class="text1">example</div>
                <div class="text2">example</div>
                <div class="text3">example</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So I want to move text3 as the first child of text-parent. But only in its own parent element. So text3 should not move to the other `<li>` elements. I have tried this, but it's not correct, it still crosses all elements:

```
$('.text3').parent('.text-parent').prependTo('.text-parent');
```

***How do I limit the function to its parents?***

Comment: you want to move each `.text3` "before" `.text1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong because it select all `.text-parent` and insert every one in another. You need to loop through `.text3` using `.each()` and in function select relevant parent of elements.

```
$('.text3').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
  // Or
  $(this).parent('.text-parent').prepend(this);
  // Or
  $(this).prependTo($(this).parent('.text-parent'));
});
```

```js
$('.text3').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

```css
.text-parent {border: 1px solid #000}
.text-parent > .text3 {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-element">          
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text-parent">
                <div class="text1">example</div>
                <div class="text2">example2</div>
                <div class="text3">example3</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text-parent">
                <div class="text1">example</div>
                <div class="text2">example2</div>
                <div class="text3">example3</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text-parent">
                <div class="text1">example</div>
                <div class="text2">example2</div>
                <div class="text3">example3</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

```
 $(this).insertBefore($(this).siblings('.text1'));
```

```js
$(".text3").each(function(){
  $(this).insertBefore($(this).siblings('.text1'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-element">          
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text-parent">
                <div class="text1">example</div>
                <div class="text2">example</div>
                <div class="text3">example3</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text-parent">
                <div class="text1">example</div>
                <div class="text2">example</div>
                <div class="text3">example3</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="text-parent">
                <div class="text1">example</div>
                <div class="text2">example</div>
                <div class="text3">example3</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```